# Android SQLite group by - all columns?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, group-by

Is it legal in all versions of SQLite in Android (say from Android 1.6 - up) to have a query like this:

```
select _id, name, min(qty) min_qty, max(qty) max_qty 
from my_table
group by name
```

Please note: grouping is by 'name' only, not by '_id'. I've noticed this actually works. I just wonder if it works like this by purpose and on any Android version and device. I need this query to display min and max quantities on my ListView but still have an _id of one of the rows grouped - for my ListView to get it.
Hope it is clear.

Comment: SQLite is independent of Android, and the query is valid for SQLite (as well as MySQL) though not for other databases.  The GROUP BY clause is technically ANSI, though that's not what most databases (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, etc) support.  I believe PostgreSQL 9.2 started supporting the "missing column" GROUP BY...

Comment: OK thanks a lot. Anyway I'd love to see some other confirmation on this.

Comment: To add to what OMG said, it works correctly if `name` is Unique. If it isn't unique, one (more or less random) `_id`, of the many that are related to `name`, is returned. So, if (as you say) just want one (any) `_id` of one of the rows grouped, you can use it.

Comment: Yes, I need just one (any) id of the items in the group. Thank you two. However, my actual query is more complicated and I group by a few more columns. In this case name can appear in some other rows, but I assume that the id I will obtain will be one of the ids in this particular group displayed on the list.

Comment: No, it doesn't work on all Android versions, the `GROUP BY` clause is not supported on Android ICS, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837544/android-ics-sqlite-error

Comment: I've just tested my app on an Android 4.0 emulator and it works perfectly well. GROUP BY is working. Probably the author of the other thread had some other problem. By the way, I am not using any content providers. Just plain good old database adapter and queries / raw queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by OMG Ponies and ypercube I think I can say this question is answered:  yes, the query is valid, and an _id returned will be one of the group.